# Limiting the number of characters per line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

How can I make sure that 50 characters are shown in block (width:100px;) with CSS if User posts 50 characters on one line.
Now, my view is below.

```
    <div class='example-wrapper'>
      <%= simple_format(@user.content , class:'example')  %>
    </div>
```

If User posts 50 characters on one line(without making a line break) in @user.content, it is sticking out from browser.I don't mean that I use overflow:hidden;.Although I use white-space:normal; , nothing changes. Please tell me how to do it.

Now, scss is below.

```
        .example-wrapper{
          background-color:red;
          max-width:100px;
        }
       .example{
            max-width:100px;
            white-space:normal;
        }
```

Comment: Is it really important to have a line break after 30 chars? I mean 30 'Q' are much wider than 'i'? Or do you want to have a maximum wide in px or `em`? Btw. how does your css for that block and the surrounding blocks look like?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I want to show it in block (width:100px;).Sorry, I added css above.Please tell me.

Comment: So what do you want to happen the the text that is longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `truncate` method. An example:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17)
# => "Once upon a ti..."
```

Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

With your example it would be something like this:

```
<div class='example-wrapper'>
  <div class='example'>
    <%= trucate(simple_format(@user.content), length: 50)  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. See this code pen as an example of what I suggest: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbMVZE

You can use the truncate method along with the word-wrap property to limit the words and wrap all of the text around the column.